# Android Wear Set up Environment can't connect to emulator

Tags: android, terminal, android-studio, adb, wear-os

So, I am trying to set up the Android Wear Environment, I already  signed up for the developers preview and I already got confirmed I have my support library, app samples, my Android Wear Preview app installed on my device etc etc. The only problem is that I can't connect the Android Wear Preview app with the emulator. I am using Android Studio and I've already tried everything and nothing works, I tried with Eclipse same result. Please help because this is the only thing holding me back. I attached an image on my Terminal so you can see the error thanks. this is the a error i get. BTW I am using adroid studio

Ronny-Perezs-MacBook-Pro:~ ronnyperez$ cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools/

Ronny-Perezs-MacBook-Pro:platform-tools ronnyperez$ adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601

-bash: adb: command not found

Comment: Do you have `.` in your `PATH`? If not try ./adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601 instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]You should be able to resolve by making sure you've done the following:
http://developer.android.com/preview/google-play-services-wear.html (you've done most of this, but double check, especially pt 4)

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

Also, double check your Android SDK manager and see that you have the Android support repository and library, Google Play Services 5.0, all the necessary tools in 4.4W, latest build tools, platform, etc.

Resync Gradle Afterwards (edit: you also need latest Android Studio and newer gradle, see the second link; added pictures of my installed packages

Comment: I tried everything and still doesn't work now I'm getting this errorError:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Open in Project Structure dialog</a><br><a href="openFile">Open File</a>Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.support:wearable:+
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Open in Project Structure dialog</a><br><a href="openFile">Open File</a>